# Implement timer for web-application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

I am creating a website that uses timer in it. I have used one `.js` in it. But every time I refresh my application, it gives incorrect time.

Any suggestion how to correct time?

Comment: When you say "timer", do you mean like showing what the time is right now, or do you want to schedule some action to happen at a certain time in the future? If it's an action you want to schedule, is it a server side action (ASP.NET method) or client side action (Javascript method) you want to schedule?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a hidden field with enabled ViewState and store a time value into it so a value will be persisted across post backs.

Answer (score 0):

You should to store time value into hidden field, or in user's session and correct it every time when user refresh page.

Comment: how you would store a value from JS into a session? I see only one way - via AJAX